# Is it wrong to use the domain account in IIS?

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I am trying to deploy my webiste on a server.

I used the `Domain account` in deploying. But I kept getting `"error in parsing xml"` in firefox and empty page on chrome. I tried to deploy it on another server suing `wubdiws admin account` and it works.

So I thought that maybe using the `domain account` is wrong. Am I right?

**Note:**

Static content already installed on IIS roles.

Comment: IMO, It should not be wrong but certainly the level of authorization may cause problems while accessing files!

Comment: Without more information; it's impossible to tell what the actual source of the problem you face is. There could be a few differences.  Take a fresh project; deploy it to one server, and then deploy that same project cleanly to another server.  Then, detail the exact configuration and steps you used so that we can try to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker that is what I am doing, my web page is very simple, just a button and an image, i can deploy it on a server, but when I deploy it on another server (using domain account) I got `XML Parsing Error: no element found`

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Can you reproduce it with a stock ASP.NET application? Like the one that Visual Studio 2013 produces when you click "New ASP.NET Application"? When you do that; does the error log say anything? Does the domain account you are deploying it as have permissions? What's the AppPoolIdentity set to; etc. etc.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker the log has this `2014-09-24 11:54:49 ::1 GET /index.aspx - 8091 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:32.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/32.0 500 24 50 22`. and I don't know if the account am i using has the permissions needed, (you may tell me how to know please?)

Comment: This question should go to http://serverfault.com. If you only have static file enabled, that's not enough for ASP.NET (.aspx). Note that in some cases `aspnet_regiis` is also needed to manually register ASP.NET to IIS. `500.24` is a typical error status indicating such configuration problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it seems that using domain account is the correct way. my problem has been solved when running `aspnet_regiis.exe -i` which locates on `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319`